# Converting MapBox PBF vector tiles to GeoJSON?

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles

There are many pieces MapBox in `file.vector.pbf`. I can get information from them in GeoJSON using tippecanoe, but the geometry will be broken(screen below).

How can I normalize geometry or combine all the pieces into one big card?

[image]

Comment: If you want all of the geometry then you might want to acquire the data in a better format than vector tile

Comment: I only have file `files.vector.pb`

Comment: From `files.vector.pb` I want to get only the coordinates of the houses